# ということで in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> ゲストハウスの当番だということで、郷田さんと熊沢さんがゲストハウスまで案内してくれることになった

I'm often troubled when I see ということで in the middle of a sentence. Looking at this sentence makes me wonder if there isn't some kind of "because" or "since" meaning implied with ということで, but as I'm not sure I'd like your opinion on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are thinking in the right direction.

> 「～～だということで」

means:

> "Since/Because/As ~~ (is the case)"

Thus, the sentence:

> 「ゲストハウスの当番{とうばん}だということで、郷田{ごうだ}さんと熊沢{くまざわ}さんがゲストハウスまで案内{あんない}してくれることになった。」

means:

> "Since Gouda and Kumazawa were in charge (of the chore) at the guest house, it was arranged that they would show me to the guest house."

Comment: Would it be interchangeable with ので or から?