# Meaning of いつ如何なる時も?

Tags: meaning

> しかし、彼は屈服しないということで、いつ如何なる時も、抵抗を見せることが出来る…。

"However, since he wouldn't surrender.... he could show resistance." I'm not sure what いつ如何なる時も is supposed to mean.

Comment: A good answer has already been provided by @Schokolade, so I will say this here.   There is no equivalent of "since" in the original sentence.  The basic structure of that sentence is "By doing A., he can show B at any time."  The key phrase is 「ことで」.

Comment: @l'électeur Wasn't ということで a way of saying "because" as you told me https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54875/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7-in-this-sentence ?

Comment: That is a different kind of ということで altogether.   This one is used to describe a method.

Comment: How do you tell the difference? Both sounds good to me.

Comment: Context, period.  Does your TL "Since he wouldn't surrender, he could show resistance." **really** make sense to you?  To me, "By not surrendering, he could show resistance." would make more sense.

Comment: It makes more sense when you add the part I didn't get, in my opinion. It would mean: "Since he wouldn't surrender, he could show resistance at any time." Anyway, both translations satisfy me. I'm interested to know something, though. If ことで is used as "by -ing" here, what does that make という?

Comment: @Ushiromiya You should rather think that that ということで in the link happens to be translated to "because/since" because of the specific context where という functions as quote from the third person's side. The question is if it's natural to interpret as "According to him, however, he will never surrender. Thus, he can show resistance".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「いつ[如何]{いか}なる時も」 is a literary way of saying 「いつどんな時も」.
(いかなる is a literary way of saying どんな).
「いつ、如何なる時も」 means (literally) "at any time, at any situation", and it's an emphatic way of saying "at any time" "no matter when" (≂ 「いつでも」「どんな時も」).

Answer (score -1):

As you know いつも means "every time", while 如何なる時 emphasizes いつも, so いつ**如何なる時**も means "every **single** time".

Comment: "every single time" は「毎度毎度、毎回毎回、10回似たようなイベントがあったらそのうちの10回」という意味ですが、「いつ如何なる時も」とは意味が違います。滅多にない事象で考えると分かりやすいでしょうが、「いつ如何なる時も地震への備えを欠かさない」の冒頭を「毎回」に置き換えると相当変です。